# Как найти в объекте число и сравнить его

Tags: javascript

Есть объект:

```
$sum = {
"document":{
    "0.3":{"in_city":"1600","0_49":"2200","50_200":"3200","200_999":"4200"},
    "0.5":{"in_city":"2000","0_49":"2400","50_200":"3400","200_999":"4400"},
    "1":{"in_city":"2400","0_49":"2700","50_200":"3700","200_999":"4700"},
    "1.5":{"in_city":"2600","0_49":"3000","50_200":"4000","200_999":"5000"},
    "2":{"in_city":"2800","0_49":"3500","50_200":"4500","200_999":"5500"},
    "2.5":{"in_city":"3000","0_49":"3800","50_200":"4800","200_999":"5800"},
    "3":{"in_city":"3200","0_49":"4100","50_200":"5100","200_999":"6100"},
    "3.5":{"in_city":"3350","0_49":"4300","50_200":"5400","200_999":"6400"},                                        
    "4":{"in_city":"3550","0_49":"4700","50_200":"5700","200_999":"6700"},
    "4.5":{"in_city":"3750","0_49":"5000","50_200":"6000","200_999":"7000"},
    "5":{"in_city":"3950","0_49":"5300","50_200":"6300","200_999":"7300"}
}
```

};

На сайте есть поле формы в которую можно написать число допустим "1.2" теперь как найти ближайший объект который больше числа 1.2 в объекте им является "1.5"

```
if( $weight in $sum.document ){
    console.log( $sum.document[$weight] );
}
```

in не подходит так как он проверяет если такой же объект или нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const $sum = {
  "document":{
  "0.3":{"in_city":"1600","0_49":"2200","50_200":"3200","200_999":"4200"},
  "0.5":{"in_city":"2000","0_49":"2400","50_200":"3400","200_999":"4400"},
  "1":{"in_city":"2400","0_49":"2700","50_200":"3700","200_999":"4700"},
  "1.5":{"in_city":"2600","0_49":"3000","50_200":"4000","200_999":"5000"},
  "2":{"in_city":"2800","0_49":"3500","50_200":"4500","200_999":"5500"},
  "2.5":{"in_city":"3000","0_49":"3800","50_200":"4800","200_999":"5800"},
  "3":{"in_city":"3200","0_49":"4100","50_200":"5100","200_999":"6100"},
  "3.5":{"in_city":"3350","0_49":"4300","50_200":"5400","200_999":"6400"},                                        
  "4":{"in_city":"3550","0_49":"4700","50_200":"5700","200_999":"6700"},
  "4.5":{"in_city":"3750","0_49":"5000","50_200":"6000","200_999":"7000"},
  "5":{"in_city":"3950","0_49":"5300","50_200":"6300","200_999":"7300"}
  },
}
const num = 1.2;

const item = Object.keys($sum.document).map(item => +item).sort().find(key => key > num);
console.log($sum.document[item])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Можешь сказать зачем const?

Comment: Привычка всегда использовать `const`, если не планирую менять значение переменной. В данном примере можно использовать и `var` и `let`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$sum = {
"document":{
    "0.3":{"in_city":"1600","0_49":"2200","50_200":"3200","200_999":"4200"},
    "0.5":{"in_city":"2000","0_49":"2400","50_200":"3400","200_999":"4400"},
    "1":{"in_city":"2400","0_49":"2700","50_200":"3700","200_999":"4700"},
    "1.5":{"in_city":"2600","0_49":"3000","50_200":"4000","200_999":"5000"},
    "2":{"in_city":"2800","0_49":"3500","50_200":"4500","200_999":"5500"},
    "2.5":{"in_city":"3000","0_49":"3800","50_200":"4800","200_999":"5800"},
    "3":{"in_city":"3200","0_49":"4100","50_200":"5100","200_999":"6100"},
    "3.5":{"in_city":"3350","0_49":"4300","50_200":"5400","200_999":"6400"},                                        
    "4":{"in_city":"3550","0_49":"4700","50_200":"5700","200_999":"6700"},
    "4.5":{"in_city":"3750","0_49":"5000","50_200":"6000","200_999":"7000"},
    "5":{"in_city":"3950","0_49":"5300","50_200":"6300","200_999":"7300"}
}
};
$("#check").click(function(){
  let need=$("#need").val();
  //Сортируем ключи
  let keys=Object.keys($sum.document).sort(function(a, b){
    return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
  });
  //Ищем большее значение и выходим из цикла
  for(let i in keys){
    if(need<keys[i]){
      console.log(keys[i]+":"+JSON.stringify($sum.document[keys[i]]));
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="need">
<button id="check">Получить ближайшеее значение</button>
```